# MongoDB $slice from each of a set of unknown subdocuments

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection where a set of devices each store measurements in arrays for various physical parameters -- such as different voltages, temperatures, etc. -- but which are not common nor predictable for each.  Example:

```
{
  device_id: 1,
  measurements:
  {
    parameter_one:
    [
      {measurement object #1}, {measurement object #2}, ... {measurement object #n}
    ],
    parameter_two:
    [
      {measurement object #1}, {measurement object #2}, ... {measurement object #m}
    ],
    ...
  }
},
{
  device_id: 2,
  measurements:
  {
    parameter_one:
    [
      {measurement object #1}, {measurement object #2}, ... {measurement object #l}
    ],
    parameter_three:
    [
      {measurement object #1}, {measurement object #2}, ... {measurement object #k}
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, some devices measure the same parameters, some parameters will be unique to some devices, and in general, I have no way of knowing what the parameter keys inside a device's `measurement` subdocument will be.

I know how to deal with this structure once I've returned it using a .find() or .findOne(), by iterating over the measurement JSON structure using pure JavaScript.

**Here's where I need help**:  Once these parameter arrays grow to a significant size, I only actually want to slice off the last few hundred of each of their elements in my find() or findOne(), rather than return the whole device record and then iterate over and slice off of them if most of the device record is irrelevant.

But, as indicated, I can't just say `$slice: {measurements.parameter_key: -N}` because I don't know, a priori, what those parameter_key's will be for any given device record.  Is there a way, in the Mongo query, to iterate over unknown subdocuments and apply a $slice to each of them, without specifying the key of each array to be sliced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd need to know more about your use case to be definitively helpful, but from what I'm hearing I think you should consider reorganizing the data. I would organize the data so a document represents a single measurement of a single parameter from a single device at a single moment of time:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(...),
    "device_id" : 1,
    "parameter" : "parameter_one",
    "measurement" : { // measurement object - whatever this looks like },
    "date" : ISODate(...)
}
```

To find the equivalent of the last few hundred entries of a device's measurement array, index `{ "device_id" : 1, "date" : -1 }`, then sort by descending `date` and use limit:

```
db.measurements.find({ "device_id" : 1 }, { "date" : -1 }).limit(691)
```

It's hard to know if this is a useful change for you from what you've described of the use case, though. Why don't you know what a given device measures? What are you doing with the mystery measurements that a device may or may not produce? What is the use going to be of retrieving the last few hundred entries for a mystery parameter for a specific device? I might be able to improve the answer with more information like this. You may end up having to query for the parameters captured by a given device and then using that information to query for the information that you want.

At the least, the structure you use above is troubled because it involves multiple arrays growing without bound. This is bad because growing the arrays will cause the document to have to be moved on disk a lot. Forget about indexing the arrays - the performance will be terrible.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it's precisely what I ended up doing!  Just a collection of individual measurements that I select subsets from by specifying a series of identifiers.

Comment: By the way, the reason I don't know what parameters devices are measuring is because it entirely depends on C++ code that users will compile and upload to the device, and which I have no control over.  Whatever parameters are declared and transmitted from that C++ code should automatically enter the database as a new parameter type.